# How can I hide a listviews Vertrical Scroll bar on UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

So I am trying to hide the vertical scroll bar of a `ListView` in my `UWP` application programatically in code.

I have tried looking at the [MSDN documentation for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx)

But can't see a property. All I can find is the property `ShowsScrollingPlaceholders` which states:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the view shows placeholder
>   UI for items during scrolling.

But setting:

```
(Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView).ShowsScrollingPlaceholders = false;
```

does nothing.

So is it possible to hide the Vertical scroll bar on a listview using UWP?

Comment: Did you try `<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></ListView>` ?

Comment: @M.Hassan Is that possible to do programatically? as I am doing it in code

Comment: Of course you can. I'm writing you an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Xaml you can do the following:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"></ListView>
```

and in code you can do:

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility((Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView), Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);
```

Comment: Didn't know it could be done in a line in code behind. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access `ScrollViewer` that's inside your `ListView`. You can do so by using a helper method

```
public ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject o)
{
    if (o is ScrollViewer)
    {
        return o as ScrollViewer;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(o); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(o, i);
        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        if (result == null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
// Get ListView's ScrollViewer
ScrollViewer listScrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(listView);

// Set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to hidden
listScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it does indeed work. Your comment on my question however put me on the correct path and I ended up using the following: `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer.SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility((Control as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView), Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden);` which is a lot simpler